# Как извлечь элементы из списка по совпадению части ключа

Tags: python, list, перебор

Есть список с элементами:

```
['60479-36403', '60482-36405','60479-52397', '365333-64094']
```

есть ключ в переменной:

```
60479
```

Получить в результате нужно это:

```
60479-36403
60479-52397
```

Подскажите, извиняюсь если вопрос задал не корректно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Но это же простейшая учебная задача, её можно решить сразу несколькими методами. Что вы уже пробовали делать? В частности можно использовать функцию `startswith`, можно использовать срезы, можно использовать `in`, добавив `'-'` к искомой строке.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: я справился. Я элементы списка (присвоим элемент переменной) разделил на левую часть и правую. И через цикл запустил перебор на поиск сравнений. При нахождении сравнения записал в отдельный список найденные элементы.

Comment: Да, тоже вариант. Вы молодец, так держать :)

Comment: Спасибо, я только учусь. :) Очень нравится обращаться к Python как к средству анализа данных и автоматизаций некоторых процессов. В работе помогает. :)

Comment: Ну вот на будущее. На этом сайте принято сначала стараться что-то сделать, и только если никак не получается и поиском ничего не находится - тогда задавать вопрос. И показывать в вопросе, что именно вы пытались и что не получилось. Тогда обязательно помогут.

Comment: Я уже отчаялся искать решение. У меня всегда так, начинаю писать код, первый час-полтора более менее что то адекватное пишу (как кажется), а потом начинаются пробуксовки как в следствии оказывается на очень очевидных вещах). Спасибо за рекомендации, в следующий раз обязательно попробую более информативно приводить пример с кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам ещё вариантик:

```
sp=['60479-36403', '60482-36405','60479-52397', '365333-64094']
z=input()
for i in sp:
    if z == i.split('-')[0]: print(i)
```

Comment: Судя по одному из комментариев автора вопроса, он именно так и решил ;)